# node-sspi works on localhost but not when using the IP address

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on

I'm running the example node script provided by [node-sspi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi). Using Chrome, when I go to localhost, it works great. It doesn't ask for my credentials, instead, my session is properly authenticated using Active Directory.
When I use the IP address however, it asks for my credentials first, and then it will validate them with the Active Directory.

I'm trying to use this for Single-Sign-On, so while the Active Directory validation is great, I don't want to have to require for username and password.

**Relevant information:**

- Both servers are running Windows Server 2008 R2, and my active Directory setup has been validated by dcdiag.
- The SSPI package I'm using is Negotiate but I have experienced the same behavior with NTLM.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE and chrome only allow transparent auth for sites in IE trusted intranet zone list. Usually this list is maintained by GPO for windows computer joined a domain. But you can manually add your ip to the list.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I was missing the addition of the site to the Local Intranet; here is the link for how to do it: [aws instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ie_sso.html)